# cannot make sqlcmd work after runas

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd, runas

I followed a few examples here, but I still can not get my sqlcmd work after runas.

I can make it work with two steps:

1. Step one:  Use runas to login into a new login and open a command prompt:

   runas.exe /savecred  /user:DOMAIN_NAME\login_name cmd.exe
2. Step two: execute the sqlcmd in a script

   sqlcmd -S server_name -E /Q"exit(SELECT @@version )"

But I want to make it one step to get the results.  I tried to add " " after the runas command as listed below, but it did not work:

```
runas.exe /savecred  /user:DOMAIN_NAME\login_name "sqlcmd -S server_name -E /Q"exit(SELECT @@version )""
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to escape your inner quotes

Comment: I added escape "\" before the " inside my quote. It did not work.  Continue to look for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [at this article describing RunAs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/04/28/how-can-i-use-the-runas-command-to-run-a-script-under-alternate-user-credentials.aspx). Toward the end of the article, he specifically addresses needing to use quotes inside of quotes:

> Fortunately, it’s fairly easy to make RunAs happy. All you need to do is use the \ character to “escape” any double quote marks that must to be embedded within the process path.

So, it looks like your command should be:

```
runas.exe /savecred  /user:DOMAIN_NAME\login_name "sqlcmd -S server_name -E /Q\"exit(SELECT @@version )\""
```

Notice the `\` before **both** of the nested double quotes.